# XVFB and Selenium on EC2 - Unable to view Chrome UI on VNC Viewer

Tags: selenium, ubuntu, jenkins, amazon-ec2, xvfb

My Selenium headless tests are triggered from Jenkins server and run in EC2-Ubuntu.  I want to view the test live on Chrome so I installed Xvfb plugin on Jenkins.

On EC2 I installed Xvfb. When I start executing the build, my test starts execution  and I see below logs:

`Xvfb  /usr/bin/Xvfb :1 -fbdir /var/lib/jenkins/xvfb` `27-..fbdir13700092919317283985`

```
Parsing POMs
Established TCP socket on 30810
```

and I see the test is running successfully.

Now I do SSH to EC2 from Mac terminal by

```
ssh -L 5901:localhost:5901 qa_user@10.113.x.xxx
```

Then I execute:

```
qa_user@jenkins-it:~$ export DISPLAY=: 30810` (Port number from Jenkins logs above)
qa_user@jenkins-it:~$ vncserver "$DISPLAY" -geometry 1280x1024

New 'X' desktop is jenkins-it: 30810

Starting applications specified in /home/qa_user/.vnc/xstartup
Log file is /home/qa_user/.vnc/jenkins-it: 30810.log

qa_user@jenkins-it:~$ x11vnc --listen 0.0.0.0 -rfbport 5901 -display : 30810
```

This starts XVFB and I see:

[image]

Now when I connect from Mac to localhost:5901 from VNCviewer, I am taken to Ubuntu desktop.

[image]

But I don't see chrome opening up even though the test is running and I see test logs on Jenkins.

I am also able to use Chrome via VncViewer.
[image]

What am I missing here?
I tried many Xvfb set up instructions and has been trying to get this right since a month now. Here are few questions I asked:

https://askubuntu.com/questions/1262925/run-selenium-tests-on-ec2-with-gui?noredirect=1#comment2139716_1262925

[How to view live headless Selenium tests on EC2-Ubuntu using vncserver and xvfb](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63217945/how-to-view-live-headless-selenium-tests-on-ec2-ubuntu-using-vncserver-and-xvfb?noredirect=1#comment111814101_63217945)

https://sqa.stackexchange.com/questions/45376/looking-for-a-solution-to-run-selenium-tests-on-ec2-with-gui/45380#45380

Long way till here and now Stackoverflow is my last resort. Please help.

Comment: You talking about Selenium "headless". Are you running ChromeDriver with headless flags? If Chrome runs in headless mode you will never see the UI.

Comment: Yes. I have set chrome options to headless. If I don't, I believe it will throw 'Cannot find Chome Binary' error. Or at least before installing Xvfb it did. Are you suggesting to remove headless flags and try in xvfb?

Comment: Yes. You must remove headless flags. Chrome headless flags, well, actually make the browser not spawn graphically. If you have a different error, edit the question after removing the flags or even better ask another question and we check that out.

Comment: I get below error if I remove  options.addArguments("--headless"); from my code.

org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: 
unknown error: Chrome failed to start: exited abnormally
(unknown error: DevToolsActivePort file doesn't exist)
(The process started from chrome location /usr/bin/google-chrome is no longer running, so ChromeDriver is assuming that Chrome has crashed.)
Build info: version: '3.141.59', revision: 'e82be7d358', time: '2018-11-14T08:17:03'

Comment: Does Chrome open from that VNC session you have? Like double click the shortcut and see if it works

Comment: Yes it does. Will add a screenshot of that to the question.

Also, withou XVFB, I am able to run tests in EC2 in headless mode without any issues. But a new requirement has come where in we need to watch the live UI test. I am trying to achieve that using XVFB.

Update: Added chrome screenshot to the question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/220169/discussion-between-marc-sances-and-afsal).

Comment: Update:

http://antonina.burlachenko.com/2013/09/sharing-of-remote-screen-for-selenium.html#comment-form

This is exactly what I am trying to do and I am almost there. I followed the steps and the only issue now is that I see a black screen when I do the final localhost connection step to remote Ubuntu. I guess Chrome will be displayed on this screen but I am missing something.

Comment: @MarcSances, posted the solution. :)

Comment: Glad you managed to fix it finally...

Answer (score 2):

I found the solution to this myself. For anyone who's having the same issue:

What I did wrong was I used  `driver = new ChromeDriver(options);` in my code instead of `driver = new RemoteWebDriver(new URL("http://my.aws.ip:4444/wd/hub"), options);`

After making this change, I downloaded selenium-server-standalone.jar to in EC2.

Then, before starting the test, I did ssh -X qa_user@my.aws.ip to EC2 and executed:

```
Xvfb :99 -ac -screen 0 1280x1024x24 &
export DISPLAY=:99
java -jar /home/qa_user/Selenium/selenium-server-standalone.jar
```

Now, execute the test, in parallel I opened a new terminal and did:

`ssh -L 5900:localhost:5900 qa_user@my.aws.ip`

Once the screen was set, I did:

```
x11vnc -xkb -noxrecord -noxfixes -noxdamage -display :99 -auth /var/run/lightdm/root/:0  -rfbport 5900
```

Next, open VNC viewer, connect to localhost:5900 and you'll see Chrome execution.

Later you can move all this to Jenkins pre-build execute shell if required :)

More details on my latest answer :
[XVFB on Jenkins connecting to wrong display. Display shows black screen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63935935/xvfb-on-jenkins-connecting-to-wrong-display-display-shows-black-screen)